# Dual of $(C_\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

What is the dual space of $X = (C_\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$, the continous functions that approach zero at infinity? Is it reflexive?

Additionally, is there a Banach space $Y$ such that $X=Y'$?

Comment: The dual is the space of finite signed measures on $\mathbb R^n$.  No, it is not reflexive.  No, it is not a dual of a Banach space.  It looks like you need to read a textbook on Banach spaces...

Comment: Probably I do need precisely that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Think yourself about the "discrete analogue" $c_0$.